# How to compare number with filenames in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I have number of multiple files in a folder and their filenames contains alphanumeric values. For e.g. 045_gfds.sql, 46kkkk.sql, 47asdf.sql etc. I want to compare numbers in these filenames with another number stored in variable lets say $× =45 and find out files which has greater than number contain in filename. I am using Cygwin and currently only able to retrieve numbers using egrep command. for e.g.

```
filename="C:\scripts"
dir $filename | egrep -o [0-9]+
```

Output is : 045 46 47

I want output as filename after comparing greater than $=45 with all the filenames as:

```
46kkkk.sql
47asdf.sql
```

Need help with regular expressions for comparing greater than values in filename.

Comment: This is looking like a question for the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). But perhaps not. I advise you to explain **what** you want to achieve, not **how** you are trying to achieve. There's probably a better solution. Read here: [The XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thanks giusti, I want output as filenames, which contains number in filename greater than $x=45. please let me know if more information is needed to clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="$1"

print_if_greater="45"

for fname in "$dir"/[0-9]*; do
    num="${fname##*/}"      # isolate filename from path
    num="${num%%[^0-9]*}"   # extract leading digits from filename

    if (( num > print_if_greater )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$fname"
    fi
done
```

The above script will go through all file in the given directory that starts with at least one digit.

The filename is stripped from the path, and the initial digits in the filename are extracted using the variable expansion syntax of `bash`.

If the number that is extracted is greater than `$print_if_greater`, then the full pathname is displayed on standard output.

This script is invoked with the directory that you'd like to examine:

```
$ ./thescript.sh 'C:\scripts'
```

or

```
$ bash ./thescript.sh 'C:\scripts'
```

I haven't got access to Cygwin, so I haven't been able to test it with Window-styled paths.  If the above doesn't work, try with `C:/scripts` as the path.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda!!! Its working absolutely fine. Only problem I am facing now is its just doesn't consider the filename which has . (dot) after the number. for e.g. filename like '69.hghgg.sql' is not displayed in the result after the comparison.

Comment: @JayeshSangle Hmmm... it does for me. I even installed Cygwin and tested it. Does the file have space in the beginning of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
DIR="C:\scripts"
MAX=45
for FILE in "$DIR"/*
do
  if
    [[ "$FILE" =~ ^([0-9]+) ]]
  then
    NUMBER="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    if
      [ "$NUMBER" -gt "$MAX" ]
    then
      echo "$FILE"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Please note I have not tested this code.  It is bash-specific, and assumes the numbers are always at the beginning of the filename.